# If someone makes a profile on my console can they use my sub on their console too?

Tags: ps4

A friend of mine made a profile on my console and I have PlayStation Plus...I just want to know if they go home and log on to their console will they be getting my Playstation Plus sub because they have a profile on mine also? Or is PlayStation Plus only for the console you buy it for?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, they can't access your account or membership from their console unless you log  into their console.

PlayStation Plus is **only applied to a console** when an account that has a subscription is logged onto the console.  In order for all accounts on the console to benefit from the PlayStation Plus membership, the account with the subscription must activate that console as their *Primary PS4*.  [Here](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/activation.html) is the online manual page for activating a *Primary PS4*.

Answer (score 0):

No they can't. You can only use the PS+ benefits on your console, he won't be able to use it on his unless he buys it.